# Logic error in null clause

Tags: grails

hi I have the following function :

```
   def signup(String name){

        def x =Human.where{name == name}
        if(x != null)
        {

            def myhuman=new Human(name: name)
            if(myhuman.save() && myhuman.validate())
            {
                redirect(url:"https//localhost:8080")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return
        }
    }
```

It works fine. I can create people with different names and I can't create a person with the same name, however I was wondering in that if why do we check for `x!=null`, shouldn't we check for `x == null` because we first look if such a person exists and if does not we create it. I tried with `x==null` and I can't ever create Human, can someone explain?

Comment: If I were you I'd change the order of `if(myhuman.validate() && myhuman.save())` . First will check if it's a valid instance and after success it'll try to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

You check for `x != null` because you can not perform operations on a `null` object now can you? In fact it's more Groovy to do the following:

```
if (!x) {
    // Logic
}
```

This works because of the [Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth).

If `x == null` validates to `true`, then you proceed as normal performing whatever operations you need. However, since in your case `x` is not `null`, `x == null` will validate to false and skip the `if` block. This isn't specific to Grails, it's general programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Elvis operator, if the user does not exist you create a new one.

When a Human exist, it has an id, so you check if has an id, if not, you save it and do the redirect.

You don't need to validate the object, the save method validates the object before saving it, and if it is not validated, returns false.

```
Human human = Human.findByName(name)?: new Human(name: name)
if(!human.id && human.save()){
   redirect(url:"https//localhost:8080")
}else{
   return
}
```